# MySQL Search Join Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, search-engine

I have a multiple input search form, that has 2 text boxes. One text box for "searchWords" and the other for "specificPeople".

In the first text box, you may have "Dorchester Hotel London", and in the second, you may have "Brad Pitt/Angelina Jolie". Using ASP, I convert the second text box value to a format that my IN clause will accept, such as this ('Brad Pitt','Angelina Jolie').

```
SELECT photoSearch.photoID, Left(photoSearch.caption,25), photoSearch.allPeople, photoSearch.allKeywords
FROM photoSearch
JOIN ( photoPeople INNER JOIN people ON photoPeople.peopleID = people.peopleID)
ON photoSearch.photoID = photoPeople.photoID AND people.people IN ('Brad Pitt','Angelina Jolie')
WHERE MATCH (caption, allPeople, allKeywords) AGAINST ('+dorchester +hotel' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND
photoSearch.dateCreated BETWEEN '2011-07-21' AND '2011-10-23'
ORDER BY photoSearch.dateCreated
```

This works without errors but it's not producing records that have Brad and Angelina together. It shows records of Brad alone and records of Angelina alone. So this is where I first realised that an IN clause works like an OR.

How is it possible to amend this query, to return rows that have both of these specific names, rather than either of them?

My DB looks similar to this:

```
photoSearch
photoID     INT / AUTO / INDEX
caption     VARCHAR(2500) /  FULLTEXT
allPeople   VARCHAR(300) / FULLTEXT
allKeywords VARCHAR(300) / FULLTEXT
dateCreated DATETIME / INDEX

photoPeople
photoID     INT / INDEX
peopleID    INT / INDEX

people
peopleID    INT / INDEX
people      VARCHAR(100) / INDEX
```

Any help gratefully received... as always :)

---

An example of what is inside the tables:

```
photoSearch
photoID     |       caption         |           dateCreated
1900                Dorchester Hotel...         2011-10-03

'photoPeople'
[photoID]       |   [peopleID]
1900                147
1900                148

'people'
[peopleID]      |   [people]
147                 Brad Pitt
148                 Angelina Jolie
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join to the `photoPeople` and `people` tables n times, where n is the number of people you are searching for:

```
SELECT photoSearch.photoID, Left(photoSearch.caption,25), photoSearch.allPeople, photoSearch.allKeywords 
FROM photoSearch 
JOIN ( photoPeople AS pp1 JOIN people AS p1 ON pp1.peopleID = p1.peopleID) 
ON photoSearch.photoID = pp1.photoID AND p1.people = 'Brad Pitt'
JOIN ( photoPeople AS pp2 JOIN people AS p2 ON pp2.peopleID = p2.peopleID) 
ON photoSearch.photoID = pp2.photoID AND p2.people = 'Angelina Jolie'
WHERE MATCH (caption, allPeople, allKeywords)
      AGAINST ('+dorchester +hotel' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
AND photoSearch.dateCreated BETWEEN '2011-07-21' AND '2011-10-23' 
ORDER BY photoSearch.dateCreated
```

Comment: mmm... this looks like it makes sense and could work. I will have a play with it shortly and return. Thanks Mark

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the IN clause

```
AND people.people IN ('Brad Pitt','Angelina Jolie')
```

looks for exact matches, so the query is doing exactly what you are asking.  If you had done

```
AND (people.people LIKE '%Brad Pitt%' OR people.people LIKE '%Angelina Jolie%')
```

you would get the results you want.   If you want, you could use

```
AND instr('/Brad Pitt/Angel Jolie/','/'+people.people+'/') > 0
```

you can get the results you expect..

Try this:

```
SELECT photoSearch.photoID, Left(photoSearch.caption,25), photoSearch.allPeople,        photoSearch.allKeywords
    FROM photoSearch ps
    JOIN photoPeople pp on pp.photoId=ps.photoId
    JOIN people on people.peopleId = pp.PeopleId
    WHERE MATCH (caption, allPeople, allKeywords) AGAINST ('+dorchester +hotel' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    AND photoSearch.dateCreated BETWEEN '2011-07-21' AND '2011-10-23'
    AND people.people IN ('Brad Pitt','Angelina Jolie')
    ORDER BY photoSearch.dateCreated
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of a data row that has both names in the people field?  If a field in the people table has both names, what ID does it get?

Comment: Add the clause People.people to the SELECT list, see which of the two people is coming back...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3740/discussion-between-sparky-and-martin-g)

Comment: Add the people.people to the SELECT list, so you can see which person is coming back.  Based on the sample data, both should be coming back

Comment: Aaagh, it's still definitely producing an OR query but I can see a pattern. There are duplicate rows where both names are present but as the list goes down angelina is with somebody else and on her own etc